# Read pdf with php line by line as text appears on the page

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to read a pdf with php as the text appears on the page, not the raw text

I have tried pdfparser and get the same result as using this code:

```
<?
    include('class.pdf2text.php');

$cfile = "mydoc.pdf";       

$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename($cfile); 
$a->decodePDF();
$res = $a->output(); 

echo $res;
  ?>
```

The PDF looks something like this (scaled down simplistic example):

> Rate: 2%                    Age: 14
>
> Value: 230,000              Units: 1

However, pdf2test and pdfparser pull the text this way

> Rate:Age:Value:Units:2230000114

I have tried creating rules based on the order of the numbers (of the 4 #s, the first is the rate, second value, third #units, and fourth age). But the attachments with the data I get are not uniform, the data tends to 'swim' all over the place, or sometimes nothing is there

That's why I want to read the pdf the say I see it

Comment: Since our code that reads and process pdf files is over 10k lines long there is no easy way to answer this. They were never designed to be machine-readable, there are a number of services that will do the reading and processing for you depending on your project needs.

Comment: Text in PDF can be rendered in any order and generally, the libraries that parse PDF simply output the text in the order that it occurs in the PDF drawing instructions. There are very few PDF libraries that are capable of extracting text in reading order from an unstructured PDF. There certainly aren't any written in PHP. However, if you can switch to Java, the Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit will interpret the text drawing instructions in the PDF and can assemble it into the proper reading order in most cases. It will guess at paragraphs, sentences, and assemble a word from the hyphenated text.